# Ajax contact form return 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a contact form that I want to submit using ajax. It seems like send the data, but the only retrieved is 0.

HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.codetocode-developments.com/ela/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
       <fieldset>
                            <label for="name" accesskey="U">
                <span class="required">*</span>Your Name</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" />
                <br />
                                        <label for="email" accesskey="E">
                <span class="required">*</span>Email</label>
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="" />
                <br />
                                        <label for="phone" accesskey="P">
                <span class="required">*</span>Phone</label>
                <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" value="" />
                <br />
                   </fieldset>
       <fieldset>
          <label for="subject" accesskey="S">Subject</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject">
             <option value="Support">Support</option>
             <option value="a Sale">Sales</option>
             <option value="a Bug fix">Report a bug</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <label for="comments" accesskey="C">
          <span class="required">*</span>Your comments</label>
          <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="5" id="comments"></textarea>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-border btn-lg" style="border-color:#00aff0;color:#00aff0;" data-color="#00aff0" data-hover="#00aff0" id="submit" value="Submit" data-loader="http://www.codetocode-developments.com/ela/wp-content/themes/ela/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif">Send Message</button>
       </fieldset>
    </form>
```

JS code:

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(){

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
        $('#message').hide();

        $('#submit')
            .after('<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
            .attr('disabled','disabled');

        $.post(action, {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            subject: $('#subject').val(),
            comments: $('#comments').val(),
            verify: $('#verify').val()
        },
            function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

            }
        );

        });

        return false;

    });
```

PHP:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxContacForm', 'ajaxContacForm');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxContacForm', 'ajaxContacForm');

//Ajax contact form filter function
function ajaxContacForm() {

    if(!$_POST) exit;

    global $ela_opt;

    if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

    $name     = $_POST['name'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $phone   = $_POST['phone'];
    $subject  = $_POST['subject'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];


    if(trim($name) == '') {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Please enter your name.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($email) == '') {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($phone) == '') {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(!is_numeric($phone)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Phone number can only contain digits.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(!isEmail($email)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">You have enter an invalid e-mail address,please try again.</div>';
        exit();
    }

    if(trim($subject) == '') {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Please enter a subject.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($comments) == '') {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Please enter your message.</div>';
        exit();
    } 

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $comments = stripslashes($comments);
    }


    // Configuration option.
    // Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
    // Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

    //$address = "example@themeforest.net";
    $address = $ela_opt['contact_email'];


    // Configuration option.
    // i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

    // Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

    $e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


    // Configuration option.
    // You can change this if you feel that you need to.
    // Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

    $e_body = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject, their additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone";

    $msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

    $headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

    if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

        // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

        echo "<fieldset>";
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>";
        echo "<h3>Well done!</h3>";
        echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</fieldset>";

    } else {

        echo 'ERROR!';

    }

    die();

}
```

I usually use chrome developers tools to find errors on html, js.. but this time I don't know how to find where is the error and all seems correct. Can somebody help me find the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you don't pass an `action`, how does WordPress know what function should handle these requests?

Comment: @Milo as an answer please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your javascript is missing an `action` parameter with the data:

```
$.post(action, {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),
        subject: $('#subject').val(),
        comments: $('#comments').val(),
        verify: $('#verify').val(),
        action: 'ajaxContacForm' // <-- added action here
    },
    function(data){
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
        $('#message').slideDown('slow');
        $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

    }
);
```